# Gradually change background of navigation as the user scrolls down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i wanted to make this simple navigation go from background transparent to background bright green gradually. I got the idea of using the $(window).scrollTop() jQuery function to get the distance from top and divide it by 10 to get a smooth transition, but it still feels kinda snappy when i run it in chrome and firefox.

Is there another (smoother and more modern) way of doing this?

I really wanted to make the design very simple to induce the flat design art and give the website a lot of functionality to give it a modern vibe of simple but practical.

FYI:

i dont want dropdowns, expansions etc. so dont suggest them.
Also dont judge the color.
The activator link is for mobile(where i have a dropdown). so dont be bothered to mind it.

Markup:

```
<nav>
                <a id="activator"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
    </nav>
```

Style:

```
<style>
nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 2em;
}
nav ul{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #1adc8c;
    height: auto;
}
nav ul li{
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
```

JQ and JS:

```
if(window.innerWidth > 400){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(fromTop >= 100){
            $("nav").css({
                "background" : "rgba(26, 220, 140,0." + fromTop/10 + ")"
            });
            if(fromTop >= 600){
                $("nav").css({
                    "background" : "rgba(26,220,140,1)"
                });
            }
        }else{
            $("nav").css({
                "background" : ""
            }); 
        }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does it specifically have to change colour on *scroll*? Or would just a linear colour change from top to bottom on page load also work?

Comment: you can add `transition: all 200ms; will-change: background;` to `nav` class to make it smoother.

Comment: or maybe make it `500ms` to make it bit more smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the

```
transition: all 200ms; 
will-change: background;
```

properties to you `nav` class to make it look smooth. you can see these examples on `codepen` [1](https://codepen.io/Funsella/pen/yLfAG) , [2](https://codepen.io/jackharner/pen/bdPmQM), [3](https://codepen.io/jhiam/pen/woZaKZ)

```js
if (window.innerWidth > 400) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (fromTop >= 100) {
      $("nav").css({
        "background": "rgba(26, 220, 140,0." + fromTop / 10 + ")"
      });
      if (fromTop >= 600) {
        $("nav").css({
          "background": "rgba(26,220,140,1)"
        });
      }
    } else {
      $("nav").css({
        "background": ""
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.long-div {
  height: 500vh;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 4em;
  transition: all 500ms;
  will-change: background;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a id="activator"></a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Courses</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Log out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="long-div">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off simply toggling a CSS-class (e.g. `.alternative`), depending on how far you've scrolled. This, in conjunction with a [CSS transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) would allow you to make a smooth, well, transition.

Please see the following code snippet for a working example of this.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()
  if (fromTop >= 100) {
    $('nav').addClass('alternative')
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('alternative')
  }
})
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

nav.alternative {
  background-color: #1adc8c;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1adc8c;
  height: auto;
}

nav ul li {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 20px;
}

.spacer {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a id="activator"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="spacer"></div>
```